# Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on path 1.8.1

Tags: flutter, dart

How ı fix this?

Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on path 1.8.1 and fleets depends on path ^1.8.2, flutter_test from sdk is forbidden.
So, because fleets depends on flutter_test from sdk, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because fleets depends on flutter_test from sdk, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1

```
    dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  video_player: ^2.4.5
  image_cropper: ^2.0.3
  image_picker: ^0.8.5+3
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.1
  dio: ^4.0.6
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  async: ^2.9.0
  toast: ^0.3.0
  path: ^1.8.2
  custom_refresh_indicator: ^1.2.1
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.5.3+2
  flutter_slidable: ^1.3.1
  timeago: ^3.2.2
  inview_notifier_list: ^3.0.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  permission_handler: ^10.0.0
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.9
  photofilters: ^3.0.1
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  cloud_firestore: ^3.2.1
  firebase_auth: ^3.4.1
  firebase_database: ^9.0.18
  firebase_storage: ^10.3.1
  firebase_messaging: ^11.4.4
  photo_view: ^0.14.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.0
  flutter_image_compress: ^1.1.0
  linkable: ^3.0.1
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.6.2
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.4
  visibility_detector: ^0.3.3
  video_thumbnail: ^0.5.0
  dynamic_themes: ^1.1.0
  nb_utils: ^4.6.12
  flutter_svg: ^1.1.1+1
  adaptive_theme: ^3.1.0
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^5.0.6996
  file_picker: ^4.6.1
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  intl: ^0.17.0
  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
  #flutter_absolute_path: ^1.0.6

  url: ^2.0.0
  image_gallery_saver: ^1.7.1
  screenshot: ^1.2.3
  dashed_circle: ^0.0.2
  convex_bottom_bar: ^3.0.0
  another_flushbar: ^1.10.29
  video_compress: ^3.1.1
  iconly: ^1.0.1
  line_awesome_flutter: ^2.0.0
  ionicons: ^0.1.2
  share: ^2.0.4
  flutter_reaction_button: ^2.0.1+1
  filesize: ^2.0.1
  flutter_absolute_path:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/canewsin/flutter_absolute_path.git
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the version of path to any in pubspec.yaml

```
path: any
```

This should fetch the correct version of this package.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command to update the packages used by flutter and flutter_test:

```
flutter update-packages --force-upgrade
```

This command is mentioned in the [official docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#updating-package-dependencies) and in the pubspec.yaml files located at

- flutter/packages/flutter/pubspec.yaml
- flutter/packages/flutter-test/pubspec.yaml

Setting the version of a dependency to "any" is typically not recommended since it won't be clear at during development what version your app is using.