# Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on path 1.8.2 other package depends on path ^1.8.3,

Tags: flutter, dart

(I already tried this: [Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on path 1.8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72941308/because-every-version-of-flutter-test-from-sdk-depends-on-path-1-8-1)   `openfoodfact: any`)

I want to add a package ("openfoodfacts") to my pubspec file.
When I do it via Terminal: `flutter pub add openfoodfacts` it added the version   `openfoodfacts: ^0.0.8` which is old. Current version is 2.2.1.
When I try to upgrade, I receive this error:

```
Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on path 1.8.2 and openfoodfacts >=2.0.0 depends on path ^1.8.3, flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with openfoodfacts >=2.0.0.
So, because meatcheat depends on both openfoodfacts ^2.2.1 and flutter_test from sdk, version solving failed.
```

Anybody a clue what is wrong, or who can i upgrade flutter test to path 1.8.3?

Answer (score 2):

I don't really not what flutter does, but I even reinstalled flutter, and they still install an outdated version of path.

use this command:

```
flutter update-packages --force-upgrade
```

and everything works fine.